# The network path was not found

Tags: networking, domain

I have configured the Active directory and domain in Windows Server 2008.

I am trying to connect my laptop running Windows 7 to the domain.

I use the "Computer Name/Domain Changes" dialog to enter the domain name.

When I press Ok, I am asked the user name and password.

**Issue 1**

Here is the issue.
I have 3 credentials and I am not sure which one to use
1. Domain's Administrator.
2. User profile credential created in the Active Directory.
3. My laptop's user credential.

**Issue 2**

No matter which one I use, I get the message "The network path was not found". What could be wrong?
I use a Cisco router. Server is connected to the router's port through cable and the laptop is connected through wireless connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently figured out that I have not configured my laptop's ip address to point to the DNS server.

After making the laptop's ip as static and pointing the DNS server, I was able to join the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems like a kind if obvious question, but you are using a version higher than home right?  The low end versions of Windows don't support AD features.

Comment: I always thought that the UI was disabled on home versions.

Comment: I use windows 7 ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on who has permission to create/modify computer accounts in the domain. Domain administrator always works, but domain user can work if the administrator configures it (SBS does this for instance.)
2. Make sure that you can see the domain. What's your DNS server? What do you get if you run the following command:

   `nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.<your domain here>`

Comment: This is what I get when i ran the command....
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.8fingergenie
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

*** UnKnown can't find _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.8fingergenie: Non-existent domain

Comment: OK, so what's a) your IP address b) your server's IP address c) what device has IP address `192.168.1.1` (if not one of the two above)?